# Fast lane in the UK?

Tags: uk, legal, safety, driving

As an American, I am used to driving on the right, and that the left lane on a major highway is *supposed to be* the "fast lane"...

If I attempt to drive in the UK, is the right lane the "fast lane" on major highways?

Comment: Note that one difference is that while in the US [undertaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overtaking#Overtaking_on_the_inside) (I learned a new word today, it means overtaking on the inside lanes, so overtaking on the left in the UK, or overtaking on the right in the US) is allowed, it is not generally allowed in the UK and even prohibited in many other European countries.

Comment: Funny.  Undertaking means something else to me...

Comment: Yes, the right lane is closest to the median strip and is for going fast.  Slower lanes and slip roads are on the left.

Comment: in London at most crossings there are road markings to tell you which way to look, due to the many Europeans that visit

Comment: also I find it a useful habit to look both ways all the time ;D

Comment: [Varies by state](http://www.mit.edu/~jfc/right.html)...

Comment: UK driving theory tests can contain questions regarding the "fast lane" as trick question - as there is no such thing in UK motoring law, just "overtaking lanes"

Comment: If you're really worried about crashing due to looking the wrong way, this is an extreme concern. Do you not have ingrained behaviour to look _both_ ways at all times?? I'm more worried about you killing someone else, frankly!

Comment: @Karlson : Yeah, undertaking can help you visit the undertaker.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Fast Lanes Are a No

As you correctly point out, the UK is one of those countries where vehicles drive on the left hand lane. This means that overtaking is done by passing vehicles on the right. I don't think that a the concept of a fast lane exists on UK motorways since **one should always occupy the leftmost free lane and switch to adjacent lanes on the right solely to overtake**. Indeed this is reflected [the UK Highway Code](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/the-highway-code/motorways-253-to-273):

> #### Rule 264
>
> You should always drive in the left-hand lane when the road ahead is clear. If you are overtaking a number of slower-moving vehicles, you should return to the left-hand lane as soon as you are safely past.

#### So Is Undertaking

For completeness sake note that undertaking, I.e. passing vehicles on their inside (left) lane is forbidden in the UK, except for when dense traffic conditions force vehicle to proceed slowly on parallel lanes. Quoting from [the UK Highway Code](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/the-highway-code/motorways-253-to-273):

> #### Rule 268
>
> Do not overtake on the left or move to a lane on your left to overtake. In congested conditions, where adjacent lanes of traffic are moving at similar speeds, traffic in left-hand lanes may sometimes be moving faster than traffic to the right. In these conditions you may keep up with the traffic in your lane even if this means passing traffic in the lane to your right. Do not weave in and out of lanes to overtake.

Comment: Should possibly add that as of a few years ago, "not moving left in reasonable time" was made a criminal offence (almost all traffice offences in the UK are criminal). https://www.gov.uk/government/news/new-penalties-to-tackle-tailgating-and-middle-lane-hogging

Comment: On reading further not 100% its criminal - but fixed penalty that can be placed by the police, certainly.

Comment: It _is_ criminal, but you could look at it like this: the _de facto_ "sentencing guidelines" recommend on-the-spot penalties over actual prosecution. Anyway, more importantly, when driving in the UK beware that many older drivers (and some younger drivers, who apparently learnt motorway driving from their older parents), seem oblivious to lane discipline and will happily sit in the middle lane the whole time because "they're not driving a lorry". They apparently don't read the news either, unaware of the fine and 3-point penalty. Don't be tempted to follow suit — instead, give them a big honk!

Comment: (pet hate of mine!)

Comment: I think that using your horn in a non-dangerous situation is also technically not allowed. Just overtake them and then move into the left lane - sometimes they take the hint.

Comment: This is pretty much valid in all European countries. You always drive on the outmost lane and only switch inwards to overtake. But never go faster than the speed limit. That's pretty expensive in the UK.

Comment: @simbabque - "never go faster than the speed limit. That's pretty expensive in the UK"? Really? As a UK citizen I regularly speed (i.e. 99% of all journeys I undertake). I've only been caught once, in 12 years, and the fine was £60. It's not that expensive...!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, ah, the balance between hogging the middle lane and weaving in and out.  It's not possible to satisfy everyone. (My equivalent pet hate is when you end up stuck behind a lorry because you pulled in and can't get a gap to pull out again because people grab that lane from 1/4 mile before they reach you).

Comment: @simbabque your chances are pretty good at less than ~10% over, slightly more and it's not too painful even if you get caught, much more and the penalties can get quite severe.

Comment: @ChrisH you also need to take into account what car you have. With a rental I think they might be more forgiving than with a car with continental plates. When I've been to the UK from Germany we have had numerous people tell us to be extra careful. And I do know that German police are relentless with speeding on Autobahn (yes, we do have speedlimits) with foreigners. You pay cash, and you pay double afaik. Not sure if that's the same in the UK. So far I never did that.

Comment: @ChrisH: Don't hog the middle lane, and don't weave in and out!!

Comment: @simbabque possibly true but the 10% rule of thumb is before they'll even stop you, and a lot of speed enforcement is automated anyway.  I did have a speeding ticket from a camera in Germany follow me to the UK, but after writing back querying it in English never heard from them again.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit exactly.

Comment: @CMaster: Yeah, _sometimes_ :)